# get ref in stateless component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to scroll to the last item of a list, I've no problem implementing that if there's no new component.

Here's the working code
https://codesandbox.io/s/zn12r4p9ym

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.lastNode && this.lastNode.scrollIntoView(false);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div style={{ height: "70px", overflow: "auto" }}>
          <p>1</p>
          <p>2</p>
          <p>3</p>
          <p>4</p>
          <p>5</p>
          <p ref={el => (this.lastNode = el)}>6</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But what if my list is in a new file? like `<List />`, how can I get ref of `<List />`?

Comment: What is your React version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are basically trying to expose DOM Refs of a child component `List` to its parent component `App`. If you use **React 16.3 or higher**, official doc recommends to use [ref forwarding](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) for these cases.

> Ref forwarding is an opt-in feature that lets some components take a
>   ref they receive, and pass it further down (in other words, “forward”
>   it) to a child.

Here is a demo of using Ref forwarding to solve this problem.

```js
const List = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>4</p>
      <p>5</p>
      <p ref={ref}>6</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
});


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.lastListNoderef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.lastListNoderef && this.lastListNoderef.current.scrollIntoView(false);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div style={{ height: "70px", overflow: "auto" }}>
          <List ref={this.lastListNoderef}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

## [Using Callback Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs):

> If you use React 16.2 or lower, or if you need more flexibility than
>   provided by ref forwarding, you can use this alternative approach and
>   explicitly pass a ref as a differently named prop.

Example:

```js
const List = (props) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>4</p>
      <p>5</p>
      <p ref={props.inputRef}>6</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
};

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.lastListNoderef && this.lastListNoderef.scrollIntoView(false);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div style={{ height: "70px", overflow: "auto" }}>
          <List inputRef={el => this.lastListNoderef = el} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: does Fragment matter here? why not just use a div?

Comment: @Hoknimo I just wrote it like that.. `<Fragment>` only matters when don't want break the style due to a `div`... but if it is not the case `<div>` is fine..